# unable to install libzip4 on ubuntu 19.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, workbench, libzip, ubuntu-19.04

trying to install libzip4 on ubuntu 19.04 for mysql-workbench dependency

Install method:

`sudo apt install ./mysql-workbench-community_8.0.16-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb`

error message:

`mysql-workbench-community : Depends: libzip4 (>= 0.10) but it is not installable`

apt install list:

`sudo apt install libzip
libzip5           libzip-dev        libzipios++0v5    libzipios++-dev   libzipios++-doc   libzip-ocaml      libzip-ocaml-dev`

Tried installing php-zip with the hopes it would install libzip4 but that was fails!

I am not sure of any other way to solve this issue if anyone could provide guidance that would be amazing!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As suggested by the name [mysql-workbench-community_8.0.16-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-installing.html) was packaged for Ubuntu 18.04 which has [libzip4](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libzip4). You can add the Ubuntu 18.04 package repository to your Ubuntu 19.04 installation like so:

```
$ echo deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bionic.list
$ sudo apt-get update
```

And you will then be able to install with:

```
$ sudo apt install ./mysql-workbench-community_8.0.16-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb
```

Comment: i ran the following without success : `sudo echo deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bionic.list
bash: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bionic.list: Permission denied`

Comment: I changed the commands so they can be run when you are not root. Could you please try again with `echo deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bionic.list` ?

Comment: @K3NN3TH if the solution worked for you, would you mind accepting it?

Answer (score 0):

snap install mysql-workbench-community